# Keeping form choice list up-to-date in django

Tags: python-2.7, django-forms, django-1.7

I have a form in my admin site where the user is to select a single object from a particular model from a dropdown.

```
thing_choices = [(x.id, x) for x in Things.objects.all()]

class ThingSelector(forms.Form):
    thing = forms.ChoiceField(choices=thing_choices)
```

If I first add a new Thing object, then go to the page with the selector form, I find that the object does not appear in the dropdown. This is presumably the form was populated with choices when I first stood the server up. Testing bears this out, because if I restart Django, the new choice appears on the list.

How can I get around this so that I can create objects and have them appear on this form too?

(More info: the selected thing is submitted with the form in order for processing to be done upon it.)

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I first add a new Thing object, then go to the page with the selector form, I find that the object does not appear in the dropdown. This is presumably the form was populated with choices when I first stood the server up.

Correct, the variable `thing_choices` is calculated when your code is *first* run, and if its at the same scope as your form its unlikely to ever run again.

An easier way is to use a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), which references a model, rather than a `ChoiceField`. Like so:

```
class ThingSelector(forms.Form):
    thing = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Things.objects.all()
```

This should mean that as new `Thing` objects are added, they are able to be selected in the form.

Comment: Incidentally, how fast is your average speedcube solution? :)